# Is ti possible to have a `java_binary` target that embeds a specific subset of dependencies into the jar?

Tags: java, bazel

The Bazel [`java_binary`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/java.html) rule has an implicit output target of `name_deploy.jar`, which includes all dependencies into the `jar`. However, I'd like to include some but not all of the dependencies inside the jar.

Is there a way to specify some dependencies but not others to be embedded?

I've looked through the other options but none of them look like they were designed for this. I also asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763330/is-it-possible-to-use-bazel-query-to-output-the-full-syntax-for-an-implicit-or) to see if there's a way to observe what the implicit rule is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The [`deploy_env`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/java.html#java_binary.deploy_env) attribute of `java_binary` allows the dependencies of another `java_binary` target to be removed from the runtime class path and deploy jar.

Comment: This does not quite work for me, because I cannot set deploy_env to a specific library I want to exclude, such as `    deploy_env=[
        "@maven//:org_slf4j_slf4j_api",
    ],
`

Comment: If the answer is that it's impossible, I'll also accept that answer, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: You could stick the deps you want to exclude in a dummy binary?